# Clarification on the use of ampersand(&) in this context

Tags: c++

After a couple of days of Googling, I've finally given up and need some help from the community.

I'm quite new to C++, and decided I'd start by dissecting this code:

[A C++ program to get CPU usage from command line in Linux](http://blog.davidecoppola.com/2016/12/cpp-program-to-get-cpu-usage-from-command-line-in-linux/)

For the most part, I can surmise a good bit of it, except how the ampersand is being used in the last line:

```cpp
const int NUM_CPU_STATES = 10;

typedef struct CPUData {
    std::string cpu;
    size_t times [NUM_CPU_STATES];
} CPUData;

std::vector<CPUData> entries1;

const CPUData & e1 = entries[$i]
```

The closest I can gather is that its a Bitmask or Bitwise operator. But either way, I can't make sense of how its used in this context.

EDIT: Thanks for the quick replies! I understand now that this is creating a reference. What kept me from picking up on it was the spacing, given the nuances of any language I had assumed it had some significant meaning.

Comment: You're better off getting a good book on C++, rather than trying to dissect random snippets of code. Any good book would unveil the meaning of this quite quickly, and if you're serious about learning C++ you will thank yourself. FWIW though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in?rq=1 should answer your question

Comment: The ampersand here is used to create a reference. A simple way of explaining a reference is it is used to alias another variable. In this case the variable e1 is used to alias entries[$i]. A const reference means that you cannot use e1 to change the value of entries[$i]

Comment: About your edit: C++ in general doesn't care about spaces. In the past there was at least one case where they mattered (`vector<vector<int>>` was not accepted, you had to put a space between the two `>` to avoid confusion with the right-shift operator `>>`), but that was changed some years ago (with C++11 if I'm not wrong). By the way, whether you should write `int& a`, `int &a` or `int & a` (and likewise for pointers, using `*` instead of `&`) is subject of endless religious wars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's declaring a constant reference.

```
/* data type */  /* varname */    /* data we are referencing */
const CPUData&        e1      =   entries[i]
```

So e1 directly refers to the item 'entries[i]'